# Saving JSON to a variable then parsing with JQ

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I'm trying to return json from an AWS cli call, store it in a variable (so that I can use it for multiple steps) and then extract a property from it with jq.

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGETARN="arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole"
COMMAND="aws sts assume-role --role-arn $TARGETARN --role-session-name my_session"
RESULT=$($COMMAND) 
AKI=$($RESULT | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
```

It would appear that AWS is returning formatted json. `ECHO $RESULT` appears to output as I'd expect, showing clean JSON. However, when I pipe `$RESULT` to jq it appears to have been formatted with single quotes around braces. eg,

```
'{' Credentials: '{' AccessKeyId: ASI.......
```

This in turn appears to be throwing off jq. I'm not sure which stage above is introducing the single quotes.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: The line `AKI=$($RESULT | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')` must be a typo and would yield an error message. It probably is meant to be `AKI=$(echo "$RESULT" | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')`.

Comment: You may be able to avoid using `jq` altogether if you utilize  `--query "Credentials.AccessKeyId" --output text` with your `aws sts assume-role` execution.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428, that was it. not a typo... just good old fashioned ignorance :-) If you want to put it in as an answer you can have the tick. j_b thanks for that suggestion, I'll give it a go.

Comment: But you **should** have gotten an error message from it (something like _command not found_), and when you get an error message, you would mention it in your question, wouldn't you?

Comment: yes, you're right. I think it was something like that. I incorrectly assumed it was coming from JQ. Seems obvious now that it wasn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't feed your string into `jq` in your code. Since you are using bash, this could be done by

```
AKI=$(jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId' <<<$RESULT)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome. I didn't know about "here strings". Time to do some more reading.